# How to remove a previously appended DOM element after multiple AJAX success calls (Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to detach a form after multiple AJAX success calls in rails using .detach() or .empty() but for some reason the form keeps on appending to the previously added form.  I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

```
var evidenceScore = {
    init: function () {
      $(document).on("ajax:success", this.appendEvidence)
    },

    appendEvidence: function(event, data, status, xhr) {
        $('#evidence-form').detach()
        $('#evidence-form').append(data.evidence_list)
    }
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  sideBar.toggle();
  evidenceScore.init();
})
```

in my `appendEvidence` attribute I try to call `.detach()` and `.empty()` on the the `$('#evidence-form')` but it's not removing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

What's important to note here is here what was going into the $('evidence-form').

On Ajax success I was submitting a form through that might look something like this.

```
<form>
 insert things in here.
</form
```

On AJAX success I'm doing this:

```
$('#evidence-form').append(data.evidence_list)
```

What was going into my html file was this

```
<div class="evidence-form">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/observations/3/domains/2/indicators/75/evidences/score" method="get">
       <inputname="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    </form>
</div>
```

Therefore calling

```
appendEvidence: function(event, data, status, xhr) {
        $('#evidence-form').remove()
        $('#evidence-form').append(data.evidence_list)
    }
  }
```

Will only get rid of the whole entire div:

```
<div class="evidence-form">
</div>
```

Therefore nothing to append the `<form></form>` tags too on later successions.

**Final Solution**

```
var evidenceScore = {
       init: function () {
       $(document).on("ajax:success", this.appendEvidence)
    },

      appendEvidence: function(event, data, status, xhr) {
       $('.evidence-form').remove() //grab the form with an ID or Class
       $('#evidence-form').append(data.evidence_list)
    }
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  sideBar.toggle();
  evidenceScore.init();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$('#evidence-form').remove()` ?

Comment: So I've .remove(). When I check my logs it renders the partial but it doesn't render it in the views.  I think it just completely removes it, but it doesn't want to run `$('#evidence-form').append(data.evidence_list)` this line...or it does but it gets removed already?